# MS Access Query To Show Last Transaction

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table called tblTransactions. On this table I log all Payments and Invoices for each customer Account.  Each Payment or Invoice is its own record. In essence it's a simple accounting table showing debits and credits. My goal is to create a query which shows, by account, the last 'Payment' date and how many days ago that was. I'm sure this is fairly easy, but I've been out of Access for a while. Any help is appreciated!

Fields:
AccountID,
Transaction_Date,
Transaction_Type ("Payment" or "Invoice")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    SELECT AccountID, 
           MAX(Transaction_Date) AS LastTranDate , 
           Datediff("d",MAX(Transaction_Date),Date()) AS DaysAgo
    FROM tblTransactions
    WHERE Transaction_Type = 'Payment'
    GROUP BY AccountID
```